# Processing a string containing product variants

Tags: php, strings, parsing

I have a variable containing a string in this format "Size-XS|Size-XL|Color-Red|Color-Green". When i process it the final result is "Variations: Size: XS, XL, Color: Green, Red. The code for this is like below.

```
$variations = explode("|", $search_db_row['variations']);
 foreach ($variations as $variations_arr1) {
  $variations_arr1_exp = explode("-", $variations_arr1);
  $variations_arr[$variations_arr1_exp[0]][] = $variations_arr1_exp[1];
 }
foreach ($variations_arr as $variations_arr2k => $variations_arr2v) {
 $variation.= $variations_arr2k.": ";
 foreach ($variations_arr2v as $variations_arr2_value) {
  $variation.= mb_strtolower($variations_arr2_value, "utf-8").", ";
 }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? I think there are too much foreach's but I'm not sure how can I do it with less code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is not very easy to follow.

(I am going to assume that the variables $search_db_row['variations'] and $variation where previously initialized)

Firstly, Your spacing is not very clear: 
This way:

```
$variations = explode("|", $search_db_row['variations']);

foreach ($variations as $variations_arr1) {
    $variations_arr1_exp = explode("-", $variations_arr1);
    $variations_arr[$variations_arr1_exp[0]][] = $variations_arr1_exp[1];
}

foreach ($variations_arr as $variations_arr2k => $variations_arr2v) {
   $variation.= $variations_arr2k.": ";
   foreach ($variations_arr2v as $variations_arr2_value) {
      $variation.= mb_strtolower($variations_arr2_value, "utf-8").", ";
   }
}
```

makes it easier to see what is connected to what.

Secondly, consider changing the variable names.
Something like this:

```
$initial_variations = explode("|", $search_db_row['variations']);

foreach ($initial_variations as $initial_variations) {
    $each_variation = explode("-", $initial_variations);
    $variations_arr[$each_variation[0]][] = $each_variation[1];
}

foreach ($variations_arr as $variation_types => $variations_values) {
   $variation.= $variations_types.": ";
   foreach ($variations_values as $variations_value) {
      $variation.= mb_strtolower($variations_value, "utf-8").", ";
   }
}
```

Makes it easier to follow because the variable names themselves tell me what is happening.

As far as reducing the code/getting rid of the foreach's, you could try like this:

```
foreach ($initial_variations as $initial_variations) {
    $each_variation = explode("-", $initial_variations);
    if ($previous_type != $each_variation[0]){
        $variation .= $each_variation[0].": ";
    }
    $variation .= mb_strtolower($each_variation[1], "utf-8").", ";
    $previous_type = $each_variation[0];
}
```

two more points (homework):

- you have a trailing comma at the end of each group (this prints `Size: xs, xl, Color: red, green,` instead of `Size: xs, xl Color: red, green`)
- this could use a comment (or two)

Comment: First thank you for your answer. Interesting is that when the string is in this way "Size-XS|Color-Red|Size-XL|Color-Green" the result will be "Size: XS, Color: Red, Size: XL, Color: Green. This can be fixed by ordering the string the right way so no problem there. For the variable names yes, I have to start naming them more accordingly also the spacing so the code can be more readable. The coma at the end of each group separates them but I think I should remove it. Notes taken.